# Is there a simple conversion for this datetime format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetime

I'm retrieving data from a JSON feed using jQuery and as part of the feed I'm getting 'datetime' attributes like "2009-07-01 07:30:09".  I want to put this information into a javascript Date object for easy use but I don't believe the Date object would recognize this kind of format if I simply plugged it into the constructor.  Is there a function or maybe a clever trick I can use to quickly break down this format into something the Date object can recognize and use?

Comment: Do you need to actually operate with dates in your javascript code? If you don't you can think to just leave the string as it is.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a format that even when the Date object attempts to parse it, it doesn't recognize.  Given that the actual name of the property is 'datetime' and Googling that brings up a lot of MS and VB references, I'm going to guess that it's some sort of VB or .NET generated timestamp.

Comment: And yes, I do.  I need to compare the date of the time of the request to the JSON feed with one year ago from that time.  I Know I could just parse the string manually, but I was hoping for a premade and simpler solution.

Comment: That string is not a valid date format. It has no timezone specified, it could be china or italian or whatever. This means it's up the developer to know (by documentation I guess) what timezone is implied. Try replacing the whitespace with a "T", and parse it: `2009-07-01T07:30:09`. This works and can be easily done with a regex.

Comment: The JSON data comes from this service - http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html#earthquakesJSON  Haven't dug too deep into the site I don't know about documentation, but I did look over the data and there is a 'src' attribute which, from what I've seen, is always 'us'

Comment: `javascript:alert(Date(Date.parse("2009-07-01T07:30:09")));`  incorrectly returns the current time and date in google chrome (linux beta).

Comment: @anshul: does appending a "Z" works? `2009-07-01T07:30:09Z`

Comment: When I did it, it worked fine.  Though I can't figure out the regex I need to convert the whitespace into a T.  I hate regex, I don't understand them at all.

Comment: Correction: I printed out the date after replacing the whitespace with a T via inserting the result of t.toDateString() into a div.  The alert window behavior prints the current date.  But I'm not working with an alert window so it doesn't concern me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "date" attribute you are retrieving from that webservice is not a real `Date`, as it is not a recognized date format.

The easiest way to handle it as a Date object would be to replace the empty space with a "T":

```
var receivedDate = "2009-07-01 07:30:09";
var serializedDate = new Date(receivedDate.replace(" ", "T"));
alert(serializedDate);
```

This is not the most correct, as it is not handling timezones, but in most cases will work.

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it will not work.  The space stays a space.

Comment: Nevermind, it works.  I was under the assumption that replace() affected the string it's called upon, not that it returns the result of the replacement.  Not sure what language can/does do that, but I know there's some and sometimes I mix things up from language to language.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

```
input = "2009-07-01 07:30:09";
var res =  input.match(/([\d\-]+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);
date = new Date(Date.parse(res[1])); 
date.setHours(res[2]);
date.setMinutes(res[3]);
date.setSeconds(res[4]);
console.log(date);
```

Edit:  My original answer was

```
t = new Date(Date.parse("2009-07-01 07:30:09"));
```

which did not throw any error in chrome but all the same incorrectly parsed the date.  This threw me off.  Date.parse indeed appears to be quite flaky and parsing the complete date and time with it is probably not very reliable.

Edit2: [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) appears to be a good solution for when some serious parsing of text to date is needed but at 25 kb it is a bit heavy for casual use.

Comment: Just tested in firefox, I get "Invalid Date".

Comment: Nope.  Tried doing...

$('#date').html(t.getMonth() + '/' + t.getDay()); 

and it prints...

NaN/NaN

Comment: Yep... Date.parse doesn't work on the whole string in firefox and gives back now in the latest linux chrome beta, which is what I initially tested it out on.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit cumbersome, but the JavaScript Date object will take an argument list of YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS. Parse out the date value and pass it to a Date constructor, e.g.

```
var splitDT= '2009-07-01 07:30:09'.split(' '); // ['2009-07-01','07:30:09']
var d= splitDT[0].split('-');
var t= splitDT[1].split(':');
alert( (new Date(d[0],d[1],d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2])) );
```

Bah. Had to use the array index values instead. Yeah, that's a mess. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

var str="2009-07-01 07:30:09";

It depends on the time zone, 
and if the date string has subtracted 1 for the month.

If it is GMT time, and the 07 means July and not August:

var str="2009-07-01 07:30:09";

```
var d=new Date(), time;
str=str.split(/\D0?/);
str[1]-=1;
time=str.splice(3);
d.setUTCFullYear.apply(d,str);
d.setUTCHours.apply(d,time)
alert(d)
```

/*  returned value: (Date)
Wed Jul 01 2009 03:30:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) or local equivilent
*/