# Parse Json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

hello all i have one json object like

```
{"event1":{"title":"My birthday","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "},"event2":{"title":"My birthday again","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "}}
```

and i want to parse it like

```
[
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            }]
```

How will i do this.  i wrote this code but its givin array length 0 my code is

```
var response = eval(data);
        $.each(response, function() {
            obj = {};
            $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                if(k=="start")
                {
                    obj[k] = new Date(v);
                }
                if(k=="end")
                {
                    obj[k] = new Date(v);
                }
                else
                {
                    obj[k] = v;
                }
                event_data.push(obj);

            });

        });
```

Comment: Your parsed array got almost nothing to do with the original JSON - please be more clear about the logic involved and post correct example.

Comment: Please do not use `eval` to parse JSON at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a JSON object returned by PHP contain a date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428598/), [Is there a simple conversion for this datetime format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349236/). See also [Can a JSON object returned by PHP contain a date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428598/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
data = JSON.parse('{"event1":{"title":"My birthday","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "},"event2":{"title":"My birthday again","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "}}')

arr = []
for(var event in data){
    var dataCopy = data[event]
    for(key in dataCopy){
        if(key == "start" || key == "end"){
            // needs more specific method to manipulate date to your needs
            dataCopy[key] = new Date(dataCopy[key])
        }
    }
    arr.push(dataCopy)
}

alert( JSON.stringify(arr) )
```

Comment: how to make this so that is could take any json and produce the code form of the js?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're already using jQuery so just use $.parseJSON.  (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

You'll have to iterate over the object that is created though to turn the date strings into Date objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
    "event1": {
        "title": "My birthday",
        "start": "12\/27\/2011 10:20 ",
        "end": "12\/27\/2011 00:00 "
    },
    "event2": {
        "title": "My birthday again",
        "start": "12\/27\/2011 10:20 ",
        "end": "12\/27\/2011 00:00 "
    }
};

var response = eval(data);
var events = [];
$.each(response, function(key, event) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var prop in event) {
        obj[prop] = event[prop];
    }
    obj["start"] = new Date(obj["start"]);
    obj["end"] = new Date(obj["end"]);
    events.push(obj);
});


console.log(events);
```

Answer (score 1):

My code:

```
var datas = '{"event1":{"title":"My birthday","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "},"event2":{"title":"My birthday again","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "}}';

var dataObj = eval("(" + datas + ")");
var finalArr = [];
for(var i in dataObj) {
    var t = dataObj[i];
    finalArr.push({
        title: t.title,
        start: new Date(t.start),
        end: new Date(t.end)
    });
}

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: Why use `eval` when `JSON.parse` is built into browsers now?

Answer (score 0):

TO collect all item  of an array and return a json object
- this code is basically to get all the values of a select box .. but you can modify it as per your requirement.

```
collectData: function (arrayElements) {

        var main = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayElements.length; i++) {
            var data = {};
            this.e = arrayElements[i];            
            data.text = arrayElements[i].text;
            data.val = arrayElements[i].value;
            main[i] = data;
        }
        return main;
    },
```

TO parse the same data we go through like this

```
dummyParse: function (json) {       
        var o = JSON.parse(json); //conerted the string into JSON object        
        $.each(o, function () {
            inner = this;
            $.each(inner, function (index) {
                alert(this.text)
            });
        });

}
```